# kotlinc: command not found in vscode terminal

Tags: bash, kotlin, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am trying to execute kotlin code with code runner. I did set the path for it and it works in the default gnome terminal when I run `kotlinc -version`.

[image]

However when I run the same command in vscode terminal `bash` I am still getting `command not found`. I restarted the editor and still nothing.

[image]

Can one explain because this seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the name of your file is `hello.kt`. To compile the Kotlin code from the terminal within Visual Studio Code for the JVM, you will want to type:

`kotlinc-jvm hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar`

To run your code, type in the following:

`java -jar hello.jar`

Or to compile and run all in one statement:

`if ($?) { kotlinc-jvm hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar } ; if ($?) { java -jar hello.jar }`